# Can pacemaker retry monitor action on error?

Tags: linux, pacemaker

I created simple pacemaker agent for managing MySQL. It works quite well, but there is 1 thing that I can't understand.

When resource is "Started", and monitor action returns one of:

- $OCF_NOT_RUNNING
- $OCF_ERR_GENERIC

pacemaker immediately stops resource, and run it again. Is there **any** way to do more than 1 monitor check, before stopping resource? E.g. 5 retries in 30 seconds timeout. Of course I can set operation timeout, but that's all.

I know that I can implement retry mechanism inside of my resource agent, but I don't feel that it's the best approach.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Can you post the resource config?

Comment: Hello @FedericoSierra, thanks for your comment. I put it on github, so you can check metadata https://github.com/TomaszUrugOlszewski/pacemaker-mysql-debian

Comment: I temporarily added retry to script, but my question is still open :-)

Comment: Tomasz I'm seeing your code. Try to use `migration-threshold` greater than 1

Answer (score -1):

you have to implement retry mechanism, otherwise you will not be able to retry monitor action error.

Comment: It might be worth expanding your answer a little, as it is prone to misinterpretation.